# CW Structure of $SU$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cw-complexes

I'm reading Switzer's *Algebraic Topology* and he mentions that $SU = SU(\infty)$ can be given a CW complex structure. He also says that this implies, by a theorem of Milnor's, that $\Omega SU$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex. What is the CW structure on $SU$, and where can I find a proof of Milnor's theorem?

Comment: @MikeMiller I assumed it would be something along those lines. Hopefully someone has the cell structure for $SU(n)$.

Comment: Now that I've found Milnor's result, I've deleted my comments and posted them as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [On the Cell structures of SU(n) and Sp(n)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195525543), Ichiro Yokata gives a cell structure of $SU(n)$ such that $SU(n-1)$ (with the cell structure he gives) is a subcomplex. Then one can obtain a cell structure on $SU$ by taking the limit of these.

The result you quote is in Milnor's [On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW complex](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnorcw.pdf): if $X$ is any space with the homotopy type of a CW complex, so is $\Omega X$. This follows from his Theorem 3 by taking $C = S^1$.